# Percentage in LINQ comes out as zero

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query. Why do I get zero as the value in the percent column?

```
var qPercentage = from q in qCounts
                          select new {
                              q.Category,
                              q.CategoryCouplet,
                              q.Subcategory,
                              Percent =  100*(q.Count / iTotal)
                          };
```

Counts has valid integer values, by the way!

Comment: You probably want to cast iTotal to float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're doing integer division within the parenthesis. Try

```
100*(q.Count / (double)iTotal)
```

or if you want Percent to be an integer

```
(100 * q.Count) / iTotal
```

Answer (score 0):

Because q.Count and iTotal are integer. You should do `100 * q.Count / iTotal`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Percent =  100*((float)q.Count / iTotal)
```